# iOS: Zombie Messaged when accessing NSUserDefaults

Tags: xcode, xcode6, instruments, xcode-instruments, nszombie

While profiling the app for Zombies, I get the error below:

[image]

[image]

**Stack:**

[image]

**Code:**

When the app is launched, we access several `NSUserDefaults` properties using similar code as below.  Sometimes the app crashes on different methods that are trying to access the defaults.

```
+(NSString*)getSettingsFileName{
    prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    return [prefs objectForKey:@"SettingsFileName"];  // EXC_BAD_ACCES (code=1, address=0x8178b6ed)
}
```

I tried synching NSUserDefaults before accessing it, but I get the same behavior.

Any tips on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

```
+(void)readSettingsDataAndUpdateIncludeDomain:(BOOL)updateDomain MBMHost:(BOOL)updateMBMHost
{
    //Read from Documents directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *settingsFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:SETTINGS_FILE];

    NSDictionary *settingsDic = nil;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:settingsFileName];
    if(fileExists) {
        settingsDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:settingsFileName];
    } else {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSString *settingsBundleFilePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:SETTINGS_FILE];
        BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:settingsBundleFilePath toPath:settingsFileName error:&error];
        if(success)
            settingsDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:settingsFileName];
    }
    prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if(!fileExists)
    {
      //subscription
      [prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"Resubscribe"];
    }
    [prefs setObject:[settingsDic objectForKey:@"ADDRNAME"] forKey:@"ADDRNAME"];
    if( updateDomain )
    {
        [prefs setObject:[settingsDic objectForKey:@"Domain"] forKey:@"Domain"];
    }
    [prefs setBool:[[settingsDic objectForKey:@"Https"] boolValue] forKey:@"Https"];

    if( updateMBMHost )
    {
        [prefs setObject:[settingsDic objectForKey:@"Host"] forKey:@"Host"];
    }
    [prefs setObject:[settingsDic objectForKey:@"ServerNode"] forKey:@"ServerNode"];

    [prefs removeObjectForKey:@"ULVersion"];
    [prefs setObject:[settingsDic objectForKey:@"ULVersion"] forKey:@"ULVersion"];
forKey:@"ULDownloadOnly"];
    [prefs setObject:[settingsDic objectForKey:@"AgentName"] forKey:@"AgentName"];


    if ([[Settings getSettingsFileName] length] < 1) //This is the Line where it usually crashes"
        [prefs setObject:[settingsDic objectForKey:@"SettingsFileName"] forKey:@"SettingsFileName"];
    [prefs setObject:[settingsDic objectForKey:@"ScannerType"] forKey:@"ScannerType"];
    NSString *supportEmailAddress = [settingsDic objectForKey:@"SupportEmailAddress"];
    if( supportEmailAddress == nil )
    {
        supportEmailAddress = SUPPORT_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
    }
    [prefs setObject:supportEmailAddress forKey:@"SupportEmailAddress"];
    //Don't set SyncCalContactsMode from plist since this will overide the user's selection
    if([[settingsDic objectForKey:@"Instance"] length] > 1)
        [prefs setObject:[settingsDic objectForKey:@"Instance"] forKey:@"Instance"];
    else if ([[Settings getInstance] length] < 1) 
        [prefs setObject:@"Company" forKey:@"Instance"];

    NSString *info = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ULVersion = %@, ULDownloadOnly = %@ ", ([Settings getULVersion]==nil)?@"Version1":[Settings getULVersion], [Settings getULDownloadOnly]?@"YES":@"NO"];

    [DebugLog writeDebugData:info];
}
```

Comment: I see no evidence in the stack trace that you have located the crash point correctly. That is not necessarily conclusive, but you should verify by adding some logging before continuing too far this direction. :)

Comment: I agree with @StevenFisher - Your zombie crash is in `setObject:forKey`, and your stack trace shows this as happening in your own code at `readSettingsDataAndUpdateInci...`. But you are not showing the code from that method, so you are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks!  I just did an edit and posted the code from `readSettingsDataAndUpdateInci.`

Comment: @StevenFisher -- Can you please elaborate on what I should verify by logging?  Thanks.

Comment: Assign `[prefs objectForKey:@"SettingsFileName"]` to a temporary variable, then return that. Log **Entering** before and **Leaving** after the assignment (before the return). You've found the right place only if the crash has **Entering** before but no **Leaving** after. Even if the crash is here, though, your problem is going to be elsewhere.